Container Apps URL unable to view inside VM on Azure Portal
Need help on Container Apps URL not able to view, see error message.
This is trying to access inside VM on azure portal.

Here is the ingress settings:

Here is not using public IP.
nslookup says Unknown cant find https://...
Any help on this would really appreciated.
Adding NSG config.


I believe you are using https rather than HTTP. Enable an insecure connection via port 80 and check the status once.

If you are accessing the container app from a VM, make sure to allow the port in the NSG rule so that the container can be accessed from the VM on port 80


Container Apps URL unable to view inside VM on Azure Portal

The above error you encountered is due to port 80 not allowed in the NSG (which is attached to the VM) to access the container app.
To resolve the issue, select HTTP under the ingress type, enable the insecure connection on port 80, and create an outbound rule in the NSG allowing port 80.

Enable allow Insecure connections; follow the MS DOC for more details

Create an outbound rule in the VM's attached NSG for port 80 so that all traffic from the VM can access it automatically

After configuring all the settings, the container app is accessible from the VM

Result from outside of the VNET.


Hi @Venkat, i have tried the above configuration also i added vnet link and add a-records of the container app link but still error in VM is Non Existent Domain.

No need to create any records or vnet links. Just follow the above settings and create an outbound NSG rule with port 80.

Please let me know if you still need help.

I have all the configuration as you suggested but still url not working or even nslookup did not able to resolve the dns name. Maybe some blocking in firewall etc.?

Could you please share an NSG rule screenshot by editing the question.

Make sure the container app and VM are in the same VNet.

Adding NSG config, also VM and container app are in same vnet.

Could you please try accessing it using HTTP instead of HTTPS once?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
